# Updating a queryset via dict does not have any effect

Tags: python, django, django-models

When I try to update my model by updating a queryset. Seems like nothing is being saved.

This is my model

```
class modelEmployer(models.Model):
    user                = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
    employer_zip        = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    employer_city       = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=False,blank=True,null=True,default="")
    employer_state      = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=False, blank=True, null=True, default="")
    employer_country    = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=False, blank=True, null=True, default="")
```

This is the dictionary that contains the updated values
[image]

and this is the code I am using
[image]

Any suggestions on what I might be doing wrong ?

Comment: Please don't use an ORM call to update a *single* entry like that. Thhis is typically something that is handled by a DRF view, or by a form.

Comment: This is actually a part of an UpdateAPIView which has a lot of customization to it. So currently I am using this way. Hopefully Ill get to refactor this later.

Comment: I am just baffled why this is not working.

Comment: What does `qset.update(..)` returns? Normally it returns the number of records that match, etc.

Comment: So  `count = qset.update(**updatedFields)`returns 1

Comment: The there is a record that matched, and the query was posted to the database (since it is the database that answers with `1`).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem  but why are the changes not saved ?